# How can I authenticate my eks pods with public ecr repo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr, amazon-ecr-public

I know that there is this helper - https://github.com/aws-containers/amazon-ecr-public-creds-helper-script-for-k8s
but it says that *"This repository was archived as Amazon ECR Public today handles all image pull requests sent from workloads on AWS compute as authenticated requests"*.

I couldn't find any documentation on aws side that confirms this. My question is: If my pod is hosted on EKS with aws managed nodes - are images pull requests that the pod runs during startup authenticated with ECR Public? or are they unauthenticated?
If they are not authenticated, how do I configure the imagePullSecrets to work with the relevant creds-helper?

Comment: Are you running EKS on Fargate?

Comment: No, I'm running on aws managed nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On AWS-managed or self-managed nodes, the [EKS Node IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-node-role.html) must contain the required permissions for authenticating to ECR. Depending how you have created your cluster, this may already be setup for you by default. EKS will handle performing ECR authentication for you.

Your [cluster role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html) should also have the `AmazonEKSClusterPolicy` policy attached.

If you are running your workloads are Fargate, you must use a [pod execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html#fargate-sg-pod-execution-role) to give your pods access to ECR.

Additional references:

- [Using Amazon ECR Images with Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_on_EKS.html)
- [Sample EKS deployment using public ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sample-deployment.html)

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't say anything about IAM permissions to ECR Public repo. How do I do that?

Comment: @deez, it does. You can see the exact policy in the first reference link.